# Uses for fondue broth?

Tags: broth, fondue, culinary-uses

I had meat fondue last night: beef, chicken, and shrimp cooked in a simple vegetable broth at the table. When we were finished eating, the broth was thrown away. I could only help but wonder: are there any typical dishes made with the used broth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use this broth to make soups. It would make a great base for a number of soups such as scotch broth, but also for using for the stock for making other soups such as lentil or whatever you fancy.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You could try making Vietnamese Pho, a meal which is basically Noodles, Spring Onion and Meat of some sort (perhaps what you have left over from the Fondue) and Stock.

Comment: Ohhh, Pho is much more than that. It is pure happiness in food form. Plus good traditional pho broth uses only beef stock that has been simmering for at least 6 hours. I think the broth would make a cheap knock-off and can be better use as a base for other soups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like normal bouillon. For example you could put it in the water for boiling pasta or rice.

Answer (score 0):

What the Princess said!  Or Pho.  Broth for stew and soup and noodles and ...